# Alignment of text box

Tags: html, css

I have a few issues with a large height text box I am trying to make. I have set the line height and the height of the box. Except, what is happening is the text is vertically center aligned? How do I fix this? It should be aligned top left.

http://jsfiddle.net/s3spM/

Comment: Are you intending this to be a multi-line textbox?

Comment: @user1738522 Use html textarea instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this maybe helpful

```
#field_apply {  line-height:27px; 
  padding-bottom:80px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3spM/5/)

and if you need a multiline textbox you can use

```
<textarea id="field_apply" class="field" placeholder="Test" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
```

[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/s3spM/8/)

Comment: Thank you. For a bonus vote up, can you tell me how to combine these two css rules? input.field{width:100%} textarea{width:100%}

Answer (score 0):

You use height for text box or insted of use texarea without resize none

```
#textbox{
 height:150px;
}
```

or use textarea

```
#textarea{
  resize:none;
  width:180px;
  height:120px;
  float:right;
}
```